# Dictionaries and pairs

Tags: r, dictionary, keyvaluepair

In R I was wondering if I could have a dictionary (in a sense like python) where I have a pair `(i, j)` as the key with a corresponding integer value. I have not seen a clean or intuitive way to construct this in **R**. A visual of my dictionary would be:

(1, 2) --> 1

(1, 3) --> 3

(1, 4) --> 4

(1, 5) --> 3

**EDIT:**  The line of code to insert these key value pairs is in a loop with counters i and j. For example suppose I have:

```
for(i in 1: 5)
{  
  for(j in 2: 4)
  {
    maps[i][j] = which.min(someVector)
  }
}
```

How do I change `maps[i][j]` to get the functionality I am looking for?

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that, as in your example, `i` and `j` will both be integers? If so, you can just use a multi-dimensional array. In this case, just a 2D one (a matrix).

Comment: the R constructs for that are `data.frame` and `data.table`

Comment: Yes, also how could you do it with just a map between integer and integers?

Comment: or lists:  `x=list('2'=3, '1'=4); x[['1']] ; x$'1'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a list of vectors.

```
maps <- lapply(vector('list',5), function(i) integer(0))
maps[[1]][2] <- 1
maps[[1]][3] <- 3
maps[[1]][4] <- 4
maps[[1]][5] <- 3
```

That said, there's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do, but you haven't given us enough background.

Answer (score 4):

Both named lists and environments provide a mapping, but between a character string (the name, which acts as a key) and an arbitrary R object (the value). If your `i` and `j` are simple (as they appear in your example to be, being integers), you can easily make a unique string out of the pair of them by concatenating them with some delimiter. This would make a valid name/key

```
mykey <- function(i, j) {
  paste(i, j, sep="|")
}

maps <- list()
for(i in 1: 5) {  
  for(j in 2: 4) {
    maps[mykey(i,j)] <- which.min(someVector)
  }
}
```

You can extract any value for a specific `i` and `j` with

```
maps[[mykey(i,j)]]
```

Comment: Or you could just use a list of vectors: `list(c(0,1,3,4,3))`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich How do you do lookup, then?

Comment: This is IMHO the best answer so far as it can generalize to any number of dimensions and does not have any initial assumption on the number of elements to store.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you'd do this in a `data.table`, which will be fast and easily extendable:

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(i = 1, j = 2:5, value = c(1,3,4,3), key = c("i", "j"))

# access the i=1,j=3 value
d[J(1, 3)][, value]

# change that value
d[J(1, 3), value := 12]

# do some vector assignment (you should stop thinking loops, and start thinking vectors)
d[, value := i * j]
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a data.frame:

```
a = data.frame(spam = c("alpha", "gamma", "beta"), 
               shrub = c("primus","inter","parus"),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rownames(a) = c("John", "Eli","Seth")
> a
      spam  shrub
John alpha primus
Eli  gamma  inter
Seth  beta  parus

>     a["John", "spam"]
[1] "alpha"
```

This handles the case with a 2d dictionary style object with named keys. The keys can also be integers, although they might have to be characters in stead of numeric's.

Comment: This is interesting, check out my edit. I would like to know how to implement this when your keys are being used as index variables in a loop

Answer (score 2):

R matrices allow you to do this. There are both sparse and dense version. I beleive the tm-package uses a variation on sparse matrices to form its implementation of dictionaries. This shows how to extract the [i,j] elements of matrix M where [i,j] is represented as a a two-column matrix.

```
M<- matrix(1:20, 5, 5)
ij <- cbind(sample(1:5), sample(1:5) )

> ij
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    4
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    5    3
[4,]    3    1
[5,]    2    5
> M[ij]
[1] 19  6 15  3  2
```

@Justin also points out that you could use lists which can be indexed by position:

```
 L <- list( as.list(letters[1:5] ), as.list( paste(2,letters[1:5] ) ) )

> L[[1]][[2]]
[1] "b"
> L[[2]][[2]]
[1] "2 b"
```